# How to input image and text in EditText

Tags: android

control allow input both image and text in EditText android language

Comment: Please elaborate your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only put text in an EditText (which is an editable TextView). You would have to create a Layout and put inside the EditText and an ImageView.

Comment: I want same this image.You can help me?http://www.google.com.vn/imglanding?q=deco+cute&um=1&hl=vi&sa=N&tbs=isch:1&tbnid=xO44aPLfFd8ahM:&imgrefurl=http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/communication/deco-cute_pfqt.html&imgurl=http://cdn1.staztic.com/screenshots/deco-cute-111-2.jpg&ei=v3heTfvtOIT0cYWvtNUJ&zoom=1&w=320&h=569&iact=rc&oei=v3heTfvtOIT0cYWvtNUJ&page=1&tbnh=158&tbnw=89&start=0&ndsp=22&ved=1t:429,r:1,s:0&biw=1366&bih=641

Comment: The basics are:
<LinearLayout
    <ImageView />
    <EdidText />
</LinearLayout>

You have to play with it, changing the layout's orientation (vertical or horizontal), the size of every component and so.